# gridpanel key navigation on load

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a grid panel used for searching items. It starts out empty but it's configured store loads whenever a user triggers a nearby searchfield.

I'm using `grid.getSelectionModel().select(0)` to select the first row when it loads. But this doesn't enable key navigation with the arrow keys afterwards. If I perform a mousedown on a row  *then* the arrow key navigation will work.

I would like to just automatically select the first record *and* have the arrow key navigation enabled.

I've tried focusing on the grid, the gridview and also the first row with `grid.view.focusRow(0)` and I've tried all of these before and after calling `select(0)`. None of these give me key navigation. Any ideas?

This is using 4.1b2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJs4 have special singleton class for focus management. It calls with:

```
Ext.FocusManager.enable({focusFrame: true});
```

Just put this after Ext loading, and you with see highlighted component which have focus in present. So, you was very close to make it working, I tested and it works in my application

```
grid.getView().focus();
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

p.s. Please be sure that you have more than 0 records in your store.

Comment: That works great. I never knew about FocusManager, thanks for that.